# Copy and match columns from different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. I would like to copy and matched columns. I try this code below but it takes almost 15 minutes to matched about 20 columns and total rows is just 400 lines. Anything wrong with my code? Or any way to tune this?

```
Dim lRow As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
'Find last roe in Sheet1

lRow = ws1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
j = 6
For i = 3 To lRow
        ws1.Range("C" & i).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & j)
        ws1.Range("E" & i).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B" & j)
    'have about 20 columns to matched
        j = j + 1
   
Next i
```

Comment: If your code works, but your issue is about performance, then your question belongs in Code Review instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I think applying the code below will help you achieve your desired purpose.

```
Dim loopCnt1 As Integer
Dim loopCnt2 As Integer

For loopCnt1 = 1 To 10 Step 1
    
    For loopCnt2 = 1 To 10 Step 1
    
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopCnt1, loopCnt2).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(loopCnt1, loopCnt2).Value

    Next

Next
```